# Mixing HTML5 Canvas and Python

Tags: python, django, html, google-app-engine

I have used both of these (Python and HTML5) seperately, however I'm keen to use the full power of Python over the web using HTML5 to draw things and handle the client side of things. I guess I'm looking for avenues to go down in terms of implementation. Here are some things I'd like to do if possible:

1. Have very interactive data, which will need to processed server-side by Python but displayed and locally manipulated by HTML5 Canvas.
2. Clickable components on the HTML5 Canvas which will communicate with the server side.

Is there an implementation that people can recommend? I.e. would Google App Engine be any good. Django? Pyjamas?

Thanks - apologies if this seems a little vague. I'm asking before trying one path to see if there is a heads-up to save time and effort.

Comment: Thinking about this, is there a way to pick up events on the HTML5 canvas with python?

Comment: Thinking about this, is there a way to pick up events on the HTML5 canvas with python? So for example if one extends the data timeline in an canvas drawn element, the python will do some processing on data and send back the processed data for the canvas element to display.

Comment: Does anyone have any experience using Pyjamas? It looks like it would handle the JS/Python pathways but I have not idea about HTML5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The server side is much more developed than the client side in this case. (Rich JS libraries are a newer phenomenon, is all.) Django is an acceptable choice on the server, although I would at least consider [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).

My recommendation on the client side:

1. First choice is [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) which is a library for manipulating canvas. Excellent performance, allows event binding, rich graphics operations, tutorials are fantastic. Seems to have a very gentle learning curve as well, compared to similar software.
2. Second choice would be [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or a similar SVG library. Performance not quite as good as paper.js although it depends a lot on what will be onscreen.

Can you elaborate on what kind of things you will be doing on the client? Number of visible objects, what events will be bound to what objects, types of graphics filters you need, and so on, all inform this choice heavily.

You will probably find yourself fighting to get good graphics performance on the client, so expect to spend a lot of time on that.

Edit: Based on your comments, I think you would find either solution workable, so I would lean toward paper.js only because it's a little more fun, and if you do go somewhere unexpected it will be able to go there with you.

Since your application sounds like it has to do with a lot of charting, I would suggest you check out [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) or another charting library, of which there are several, both commercial and non-. HighCharts itself is free for everything *except* production use in a for-profit application, and reasonably priced otherwise.

Comment: A great deal of the user experience will be selecting data from plots and curves, so its likely to be very intensive indeed. Good bindings are crucial and we'll have to work very hard as you suggest to get the graphics running as smooth as possible on all platforms.

Comment: Perhaps a better illustration of what we want to do is very similar to what google does with its financial data i.e. finance.google.com, but for a very different area, but we need to display time range dependent data.

Answer (score 4):

I do exactly what you have mentioned using Django on the server side and HTML5 canvas/javascript on the client side. I'm pretty happy with the results but would like to point out that what you do with a Canvas on the client side doesn't have anything to do with what you use on the server side for Python.

Answer (score 2):

A viable approach for a rich client widget like this is to use a stack like:

- [ your javascript user interface ]
- [ a js lib for your graphics ]
- backbone.js for managing your objects client side
- django-tastypie for wrapping your django objects in a RESTful API
- django for defining your backend